# Filtering hyperref warning

Tags: hyperref, warnings, silence

In the code below, I'd like to silence the `hyperref` warning that complains about skipping the level `chapter` between `part` and `section`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{hyperref}{Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater than one}
% -------------------
\begin{document}
\part{}
\section{}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this didn't work, and my log file is still showing:

[image]

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By trial and error I found that it works if

1. You load `hyperref` last and
2. use `\WarningFilter*`, where one truncates the line at the same breaking point as e.g. in `pdfmark.def`.

Since this seems to be the only warning message of this type, it should be OK

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter*{hyperref}{Difference (\the\@tempcnta) between bookmark levels is}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% -------------------
\begin{document}
\part{}
\section{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the bookmark package instead:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\part{A}
\section{B}
\end{document}
```